# Prevent to get blank space of primary key in Entity Model

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm making a Windows Application by using Entity Framework.I have a table name "DichVu".

This is my talbe: "DichVu"[image: Table DichVu]:

My problem here is when I insert new record to table "DichVu" the primary key just have 5 characters and I get successfully. But after that I write a method to get all records in my table "DichVu" and show them on GridControl my ID field(here is MaDV) has 10 characters (5 of them are blank).

I tried to use query in SQL Server and count the "MaDV" lenght but It showed me exactly 5 characters for each record.

Here is the result for using query: [image: Image for using query]

And this is the result when I use the method to get those records: [image: Image for issue]

As you can see in the above picture. I got the issue at the field "MaDV".

Hope everyone can help me. I will be grateful to everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VarChar(10)`.

`Char(10)` will always be 10 characters long in storage, `varchar` (variable length characters) supports allowing different lengths.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did it. I have used LINQ before but I didn't know the issue with "char" datatype. I saw my old database which I created in the past and It used "varchar" datatype instead of "char".

Comment: Following up, I would actually recommend using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`, considering the non-ascii text in the screenshot in your question.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I just use nvarchar to type Unicode with VietNamese. I always use varchar or char for primary key like ID, etc.